# R: Why doesn't matrix multiply by inverse provide precise identity matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

My Matrix:

```
>mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  886  108  324  468
[2,]  280  820  783  475
[3,]  219  235  385  578
[4,]  843  672  594   74

> solve(mat) %*% mat
              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]
[1,]  1.000000e+00  7.105427e-15  1.243450e-14  1.509903e-14
[2,]  0.000000e+00  1.000000e+00 -2.842171e-14  1.953993e-14
[3,] -2.842171e-14  2.842171e-14  1.000000e+00 -3.552714e-14
[4,]  0.000000e+00 -1.421085e-14 -7.105427e-15  1.000000e+00
```

Comment: this is [R faq 7.31](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f), more or less. Floating-point imprecision. `zapsmall` might be useful.

Comment: I would vote to "close as duplicate" but can't find/decide on an appropriate one (searching on "[r] 7.31" gives pretty heterogeneous results)

Comment: I was about to write up an answer after several unsuccessful searches, but then stumbled upon a sufficiently similar prior question by searching on `[r] matrix inverse zapsmall`.